# paste on site, syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, c, syntax-highlighting, paste

I am getting a web host and i have projects with teammats. I thought it be  a nice idea to have my own paste site that has no expiry date on paste (i know http://pastie.org/ exist) and other things. i wanted to know. Whats a simple highlight lib i can use on code? i would be only using C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is tagged "php" but you "would be only using C/C++"?

A PHP solution is [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/).

Comment: Because he supposes such paste site would be written in PHP... (or it is a requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Building a highlighter for only one language (context free, with regular lexemes such as C++) is actually pretty easy because you basically can wrap all your lexemes into one big regular expression:

```
$cpplex = '/
    (?<string>"(?:\\\\"|.)*?")|
    (?<char>\'(?:\\\\\'|.)*?\')|
    (?<comment>\\/\\/.*?\n|\\/\*.*?\*\\/)|
    (?<preprocessor>#\w+(?:\\\\\n|[^\\\\])*?\n)| # This one is not perfect!
    (?<number>
        (?: # Integer followed by optional fractional part.
            (?:0(?:
                    x[0-9a-f]+|[0-7]*)|\d+)
            (?:\.\d*)?(?:e[+-]\d+)?)
        |(?: # Just the fractional part.
            (?:\.\d*)(?:e[+-]\d+)?))|
    (?<keyword>asm|auto|break|case…)|            # TODO Complete. Include ciso646!
    (?<identifier>\\w(?:\\w|\\d)*)
    /xs';

$matches = preg_match_all($cpplex, $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    // TODO: determine which group was matched.
    // Don't forget lexemes that are *not* part of the expression:
    // i.e. whitespaces and operators. These are between the matches.
    echo "<span class=\"$keyword\">$token</span>";
}
```